# Numerical simulation of SDE with Lévy noise in Python - Overflow issue

Tags: numerical-methods, stochastic-differential-equations, python, levy-processes, distribution-tails

My goal is to simulate a SDE with alpha-stable noise in Python. This is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.stats as stats

N = 500 #time steps
T = dt*N #total time
ts = np.arange(0,T, dt, dtype=np.float64)

xs = np.zeros(N, dtype=np.float64)
xs[0] = 0 #inital condition

sigma = 0.001 #noise level
a = 0.5 #alpha   
    
for i in range (N-1):
    xs[i+1] = xs[i] + dt*(xs[i]*xs[i] - xs[i]) +  sigma*np.sqrt(dt)*stats.levy_stable.rvs(alpha=a,beta=0)
```

For $\alpha < 1 $ I will at times run into the following warnings:

```
RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in double_scalars
  xs[i+1] = xs[i] + dt*(xs[i]*xs[i] - xs[i]) +  sigma*np.sqrt(dt)*stats.levy_stable.rvs(alpha=a,beta=0)
RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in double_scalars
  xs[i+1] = xs[i] + dt*(xs[i]*xs[i] - xs[i]) +  sigma*np.sqrt(dt)*stats.levy_stable.rvs(alpha=a,beta=0)
```

I think I understand why these errors occur: For small $\alpha$ the distribution becomes increasingly heavy tailed and has infinite variance, making it very likely that at some point the simulation takes too many jumps in one direction and falls off the edge.

My question is about how to best deal with this in a practical setting. Would it be legitimate to constrain the simulation to stay within the range numpy is ok with? Is there a more elegant approach? And did I diagnose this issue correctly?

Any thoughts appreciated!

Comment: Are you sure that the power of `dt` that you need is the square root? It is for Brownian motion, for Poisson processes however it is the first power.

Comment: Dear @LutzLehmann, you are probably right, good call for me to look more closely into how the Euler-Maruyama scheme works for non-Gaussian noise. Thanks! However, this does not remove my issue, if I understand it correctly. Linear scaling will reduce the noise level, but not enough to prevent this issue.

Comment: What exactly is `dt`, you use it without defining it, this is always dangerous.

Answer (score 0):

You have two problems:

1. you must use $dt^{1/\alpha}$ not $dt$
2. the SDE you choose is  peculiar since the associated ODE is peculiar and has a blow out for $x_s(0)> 1$

The problem n.2 is IMHO the main cause of the Python error you got
Ciao!